# RabbitMQ will not start after upgrade 3.3.3-1

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq, ubuntu-14.04

After updating RabbitMQ to version 3.3.3-1 using their APT repository, it will no longer start:

> Setting up rabbitmq-server (3.3.3-1) ...
>     * Starting message broker rabbitmq-server
>                                          * FAILED - check /var/log/rabbitmq/startup_{log, _err}
>                                                                                           [fail]
>   invoke-rc.d: initscript rabbitmq-server, action "start" failed.
>   dpkg: error processing package rabbitmq-server (--configure):
>     subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
>   Errors were encountered while processing:
>     rabbitmq-server
>   E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

startup_log:

> `{"init terminating in do_boot",{{case_clause,{ok,[]}},[{rabbit_prelaunch,dist_port_set_check,0,[]},{rabbit_prelaunch,start,0,[]},{init,start_it,1,[]},{init,start_em,1,[]}]}}`

startup_err:

> `Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
>   init terminating in do_boot ()`

[erl_crash.dump](http://tinyurl.com/lnu8tzh)

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-29-generic x86_64)
Erlang version: 1:17.0

I can't seem to find any information on why it is failing to start. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: maybe you have an empty config file? It seems like there's a problem picking the clustering port. (Note, erlang needs that even if you haven't enabled rabbitmq clustering)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at rabbit_prelaunch I think this could happen if you have a config file but it is completely empty. That's not allowed (not a legal Erlang term), but this exception certainly sucks. I'll file a bug to fix that.

EDIT: fixed in 3.3.4.

Comment: I did have an empty config file, not sure why. I removed it and the service has started correctly, thanks.

Comment: I have the same probelem.
I don't have config file. I search for it in /etc/rabbitmq/. My version of rabbitmq-server is 3.4.0-1.
I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (3.13.0-37-generic x86_64)